# Option result in akka-http

Tags: akka-http

I'm having an issue when trying to return an Option result from aka-http.

Basically it's a get that might have a 404.

```
pathPrefix("contacts" / Segment) { id =>
    get {
      contactService.getById(id).map {
        case Some(c: ContactDto) => complete(OK -> toResource(c))
        case None => complete(HttpResponse(NotFound))
      }
    }
  }
```

Which gives me and error of:

```
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.StandardRoute]
[error]  required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
[error]     (which expands to)  akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]
[error]       contactService.getById(id).map {
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing here has to do with the fact that you are using a `Future` and not because of the `Option`.  I'm going to assume that the call `contactService.getById(id)` returns a `Future`.  As the result of any route within your routing tree needs to be a `Route` (short for `RequestContext => Future[RouteResult]`) and your `Future` is itself not a `Route`, then you need to make a small change to handle this situation.  You should be able to use the `onComplete` directive in combination with your `Future` as follows:

```
pathPrefix("contacts" / Segment) { id =>
  get {
    val fut = contactService.getById(id)
    onComplete(fut){
      case util.Success(Some(c: ContactDto)) => 
        complete(OK -> toResource(c))
      case util.Success(None) =>
        complete(HttpResponse(NotFound))
      case util.Failure(ex) =>
        complete(HttpResponse(InternalServerError))
    }
  }
}
```

This code now handles the 3 possible outcomes from the `Future` (success with a `Some`, success with a `None` and a failure), producing a `Route` for each of those cases.  This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@cmbaxter's answer is correct but if you're happy with the standard status codes for the three cases above (Ok, NotFound, InternalServerError) then you can simplify the code to just complete directly with your function that returns `Future[Option[T]]`.

```
pathPrefix("contacts" / Segment) { id =>
  get {
    complete(contactService.getById(id).map(toResource))
  }
}
```

That is assuming that `toResource` returns a type where a `ToEntityMarshaller` exists for the type returned by that function.  Akka provdes the machinery for `Future` and `Option` so you just need to supply the `T` part.  For example if you were returning json and using spray-json then you can define a `JsonWriter[T]` and the implicits in `akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport` will do the rest.  See [spray-json-support](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/http/common/json-support.html#spray-json-support).

The `map(toResource)` may not actually be required, but I'm assuming that does additional conversion of `ContactDto` to some other type - if its just converting it to json or similar then you can drop it and use the in built marshalling support as described above.